# What will be the impact if there is a non serializable field in a Serializable class?

Tags: java, serialization

I am doing some code review and came across serializable class that contains a non serializable field. That field is neither declared as *transient*. Can this kind of code be termed as a *code smell*. If yes then why?

```
public class A implements Serializable{

 private B field ; // B is non serializable

}
```

Comment: These days, I'd almost call serialization in itself a code smell. ;-)

Comment: @Geek your question is the title of question or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will throw an exception when you try to serialize it, if the *execution time* type of the object isn't serializable.

For example, this *does* serialize:

import java.io.*;

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private Object object;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.object = "";
        // Now serialize test
    }
}
```

That will create an appropriate file - but if `test.object` is set to `new Object()` instead, then it will throw the exception.

It's not just a code smell - it's a bug, unless `B` is an abstract class and *all* concrete subclasses are serializable... or if you know some other way that it will never be serialized unless the value of `field` is serializable or null.

Comment: what happens when you do `test.object = "";` ? Object may not be a String ?

Comment: @Geek: That's the point - when you use `""`, that's fine because strings *are* serializable... whereas if you set `test.object` to a *non-serializable* object (such as `new Object()`) then serialization of `test` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This will make an exception when you try to serialize the object (unless the field is null, or the actual object is of a serializable subclass of `B`).

You have to make it either transient or serializable (or implement your own serialization method).

Answer (score 0):

It's not the field but the object this field points to may cause NotSerializableException. 
E.g. if `field` is null there will be no exception. Or if `field` points to an instance of C which is a Serializable subclass of B there will be no exception.

Answer (score -1):

This will result in an error if you try to serialize `A`. Because `B` is not Serializable. It is code smell.

Comment: Only if the actual type referenced by B is not Serializable. See the other answers.

Comment: There is no IF. The question already says that type referenced by B is not Serializable.